# SonarQube VSTS Task does not pick up Build Variable correctly

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops

within a VSTS Build Definition when using the "Prepare anylasis on SonarQube". we are trying to pass the $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber) into the Additional options like such

```
sonar.github.oauth=****
sonar.github.repository=****
sonar.github.pullRequest=$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)
sonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

however when the "Run Code Analysis" step is run, the following error is throw.

```
2018-04-10T22:26:56.9961964Z ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
2018-04-10T22:26:56.9977598Z ERROR: Failed to execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder
2018-04-10T22:26:56.9978166Z ERROR: Caused by: For input string: "$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)"
```

our source is in github hence the use of `System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber` instead of `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` which also fails when Source is Pulled from VSTSs Git Repo.

SonarQube 7.0.

Comment: Does the build be triggered by github pull request? It works fine for me. Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: what OneDrive ?

Comment: Refer to this article to share files in OneDrive: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-onedrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: How the build be triggered? Does the build be triggered by github pull request?

Comment: yes that is one trigger, we ended up resolving. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure variables are interpolated by VSTS in multi-line fields.

You can try `sonar.github.pullRequest=${env.SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTNUMBER}` to have the scanner read the value from the environment.

Comment: we're experiencing a different error from that now 
    `ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
     ERROR: Failed to execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder
    ERROR: Caused by: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request"}

Comment: Just to verify the value passed to the scanner, can you add a powershell task just after the "prepare SQ analysis" and run: `echo $SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS`

Comment: thanks @Julien your suggestions helped us diagnose why the vars were not passed in.